# Importing google calender api doesnt work in IDE but works in control panel

Tags: python

I Have been having trouble finding out how to read google calendar with a python script. I got the API downloaded and installed w/ pip, but now I can only make progress in the command prompt running python.

In the command prompt, I imported apiclient.discovery used discovery.build to create a service point, but any and all functions run from the service point say I have not logged in. I assumed my API Key was all I needed for that. Not to mention this is all in the console, and I need this as a runnable script.

In my script, It stops just says apiclient doesn't exist. My main goal is to be able to find the next RedSox game (I have all of the games in my personal calendar) and find some information about it.

I really need help. Any and all assistance is appreciated

my one line of code is:

```
from apiclient import discovery
```

then it returns:

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\more random stuff\everything\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5.amd64\Lib\idlelib\Red sox calender.py", line 1, in import apiclient.discovery ImportError: No module named 'apiclient'
```

Comment: I can, after running `pip install google-api-python-client`, successfully execute `from apiclient import discovery` in both an interactive session and from a file. Are you sure you've followed the directions for installing the module properly?

Comment: is it possible that you have multiple installs of python and installed the api using the wrong pip?

Comment: I ran that command in control panel, and I can use the API in the control panel only

Comment: that's how I know its installed correctly